# Aparece un margen a la derecha en bootstrap

Tags: html, css, bootstrap, frontend, margin

Estoy comenzando a aprender bootstrap y estoy practicando una maquetación para un proyecto y tengo el problema de que aparece un margen en la parte derecha del documento y no logro hacer que se vaya, no sé que está mal en mi código, podría hacerlo desaparecer con un overflow-x:hidden, pero no es la idea, quiero saber si me pueden ayudar a identificar porque pasa eso, ya que estuve probando con ajustar usando la propiedad container pero nunca queda igual en todo el documento. Cuando comento la linea de las tarjetas y dejo solo el nav, el footer y el carrusel de igual forma aparece el margen, así que no sé si sea algo del body en sí.
[image: Margen]

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>E-commerce</title>
</head>
<body>
   
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/logo/logo.png" alt="TechSpot"  width="70px" >TechSpot</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container d-lg-flex justify-content-around " id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <form class="w-75" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2 " type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          </form>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
      <section class="section-2 row bg-succes min-vw-100">
          <!-- Carrousel Start -->
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide " data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="5000">
            <div class="carousel-item active" >
              <img src="./images/carrousel/carrousel-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="./images/carrousel/carrousel-3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="./images/carrousel/carrousel-4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
        <!-- Carrousel End -->
        <div class="bg-primary  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center   ">
            <div class="bg-dange h-75  d-flex py-2  " >
              <h4>filters</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

      <div class=" min-vh-100 col bg-secondary d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center  ">

          <div class="row container  d-flex justify-content-around gy-4 ">

        <div class="card  col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
     
        <div class="card col-3 " style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
      </section>
    </div>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
      <h5>Made with love by Lu.dev</h5>
    </footer>

    
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f26be2d2ef.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./js/index.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: he tratado de reproducir tu pregunta en mi pc y no me muestra ese margen a la derecha, puedes proporicionar el css, quizas ese sea el motivo.

Comment: @Frnk Si que está, solo que no se nota apenas... te darás cuenta porque verás una barra inferior en el navegador de la página que puedes mover un poquito, y lo que quiere el op es quitarla, y con mi respuesta se arregla (al menos en mis pruebas ha funcionado bien)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Estas usando mal la clase **row**, pues no defines su contenedor (**container**).

Tal como dicen en [su documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/containers/):

> Containers are the most basic layout element in Bootstrap and are
> required when using our default grid system.

Es decir, todo lo de **bootstrap** debe ir dentro de algun *container*, sinó los resultados son impredecibles, tal como te está ocurriendo con la clase **row** que has puesto dentro de la etiqueta `<section>`.

Por lo tanto, te sugiero iniciar el documento, después del `<body>` con algún tipo de container, por ejemplo:

```
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">
```

Luego, debajo del elemento que contiene la clase **row**, *bootstrap* espera la definición de columnas, que no haces, y que son fundamentales también, tal como puedes apreciar en la estructura básica expuesta en [su documentación](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/grid/) del grid.

Por lo tanto cambia esto:

```
<section class="section-2 row bg-succes min-vw-100">
```

por esto:

```
<section class="section-2 row bg-succes min-vw-100">
  <div class="col-12 g-0">
```

donde definimos una sola columna que ocupa todo el ancho, y le quitamos los [glutters](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/layout/gutters/#no-gutters) con `g-0` para que vaya de punta a punta de la fila sin espacios a los lados.
y al final de la sección cambia esto:

```
</div>
      </section>
    </div>
    </main>
```

por esto:

```
</div>
</div>
      </section>
    </main>
```

para agregar el `</div>` de cierre de las columnas y eliminar un `</div>` sobrante que tenias entre `</section>` y `</main>`.

Y finalmente vamos a cerrar el div del container-fluid inicial modificando esto:

```
    </footer>
```

por esto:

```
    </footer>
    </div>
```

pues queremos que **todo** quede dentro del **container-fluid** inicial.

Ya nos dirás si eso lo arregla.

Dejo un snippet de ejemplo:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="es">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <!-- Font -->
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com" crossorigin>
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Poppins:wght@100;300;500;600&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <!-- Css -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">
    <!-- Bootstrap -->
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-0evHe/X+R7YkIZDRvuzKMRqM+OrBnVFBL6DOitfPri4tjfHxaWutUpFmBp4vmVor" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <title>E-commerce</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container-fluid">   
  <header>
    <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light ">
      <div class="container">
        <a class="navbar-brand" href="#"><img src="./images/logo/logo.png" alt="TechSpot"  width="70px" >TechSpot</a>
        <button class="navbar-toggler" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#navbarSupportedContent" aria-controls="navbarSupportedContent" aria-expanded="false" aria-label="Toggle navigation">
          <span class="navbar-toggler-icon"></span>
        </button>
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse container d-lg-flex justify-content-around " id="navbarSupportedContent">
          <form class="w-75" role="search">
            <input class="form-control me-2 " type="search" placeholder="Search" aria-label="Search">
          </form>
          <ul class="navbar-nav">
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-moon"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-shopping-cart"></i></a>
            </li>
            <li class="nav-item">
              <a class="nav-link" href="#"><i class="fas fa-user-alt"></i></a>
            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
      </div>
    </nav>
  </header>

  <main>
  
      <section class="section-2 row bg-succes min-vw-100">
      <div class="col-12 g-0">
      
          <!-- Carrousel Start -->
        <div id="carouselExampleIndicators" class="carousel slide " data-bs-ride="carousel">
          <div class="carousel-indicators">
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="0" class="active" aria-current="true" aria-label="Slide 1"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="1" aria-label="Slide 2"></button>
            <button type="button" data-bs-target="#carouselExampleIndicators" data-bs-slide-to="2" aria-label="Slide 3"></button>
          </div>
          <div class="carousel-inner" data-bs-interval="5000">
            <div class="carousel-item active" >
              <img src="./images/carrousel/carrousel-2.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="./images/carrousel/carrousel-3.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
            <div class="carousel-item">
              <img src="./images/carrousel/carrousel-4.jpg" class="d-block w-100" alt="...">
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>        
        <!-- Carrousel End -->
        <div class="bg-primary  d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center   ">
            <div class="bg-dange h-75  d-flex py-2  " >
              <h4>filters</h4>
            </div>
          </div>

      <div class=" min-vh-100 col bg-secondary d-flex align-items-center justify-content-center  ">

          <div class="row container  d-flex justify-content-around gy-4 ">

        <div class="card  col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
     
        <div class="card col-3 " style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="card col-3" style="width: 18rem;">
          <img src="..." class="card-img-top" alt="...">
          <div class="card-body">
            <h5 class="card-title">Card title</h5>
            <p class="card-text">Some quick example text to build on the card title and make up the bulk of the card's content.</p>
            <a href="#" class="btn btn-primary">Go somewhere</a>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>

      </div>
      </div>
      
      </section>
    </main>

    <footer class="footer">
      <h5>Made with love by Lu.dev</h5>
    </footer>
    </div>

    
<script src="https://kit.fontawesome.com/f26be2d2ef.js" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.2.0-beta1/dist/js/bootstrap.bundle.min.js" integrity="sha384-pprn3073KE6tl6bjs2QrFaJGz5/SUsLqktiwsUTF55Jfv3qYSDhgCecCxMW52nD2" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="./js/index.js"></script>    
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Hola! Muchas gracias por tomarte el tiempo para ayudarme! sin embargo, todavía los márgenes siguen presentes aún aplicando esa solución.. voy a probar con iniciar nuevamente el proyecto.

Comment: Copia el snippet completo y compruebalo de nuevo. Fíjate que en el snippet, si lo ejecutas, no sucede.

Comment: @LucasCabral Revisa mi respuesta de nuevo, le he quitado los glutters a la columna para que vaya de punta a punta de la fila (si es que era eso lo que te molestaba también)

Comment: Tal vez no se vea pq el nav y el footer no tiene color en la ejecución, pero la barra horizontal no desaparece, y cuando copio y pego el snippet en el vs, el nav y el footer terminan siendo más cortos, continuo probando otras opciones pero sigue sin desaparecer

Comment: Vale, perdona, la de abajo, pense que te referias a una linea o algo asi entre el nav y el resto... mmmm... pues eso que dices del color no tiene sentido... en cuanto al nav, piensa que usas un div container ahí dentro y es lógico que sea más corto (usa container-fluid si lo quieres ensanchar más)... en cuanto al footer ni idea, no se que hace la clase footer ni de donde sale... [aqui](view-source:https://getbootstrap.com/docs/5.2/examples/footers/) tienes ejemplos de footer en bootstrap

Comment: Si acaso prueba mi respuesta comentando esta línea: `<link rel="stylesheet" href="./css/styles.css">` para descartar que el problema no lo tengas en tu css personalizado, y si es así deberías ponerlo en la pregunta también para poderte ayudar mejor.